# TFS Workspace and Workfold conflicting on Linux with hosted TFS (VisualStudio.com)

Tags: linux, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to TFS and get code stored on the hosted TFS (ie - visualstudio.com) down to my linux web server.

I have installed the TFS command-line client (tf.exe)

i run the following command:

```
$ tf workspace -new "My - Workspace" -collection:https://me.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection -login:user,pass
```

then, i list the workspaces:

```
$ tf workspaces

Collection: https://gotmike.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/

Workspace            Owner       Computer           Comment

-------------------- ----------- ------------------ -------------
My - Workspace       My Name     ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
```

all seems good...

then, i try to run workfold...

```
$ tf workfold -map -login:user,pass -server:http://me.visualstudio.com -workspace:"My - Workspace" '$/My - Workspace/My - Workspace' '/home/me/test'

An argument error occurred: The workspace 'My - Workspace' could not be found.
```

how can it not be found if it's showing up in the list?  what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `/server` flag is deprecated and should not be used against recent servers (those that have "project collections", like Visual Studio Online.)  Instead use the `/collection` flag, like you did in the first example.  The workspace should then be able to be found in the specified project collection.

For example:

```
tf workfold -map -login:user,pass -collection:https://me.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection -workspace:"My - Workspace" '$/My - Workspace/My - Workspace' '/home/me/test'
```